# NDde server stops getting OnAdvise callbacks after a while

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ndde

I am using NDde (http://ndde.codeplex.com/) library to set up a server that receives real-time data through a TCP socket and exposes it through DDE protocol.

It certainly works well, but after a random time (between 2 and 20 minutes) it stops updating the data on DDE clients.

Once it stops responding, I can see int the logs that the TCP data is pushed as expected, and my NDde server calls the Advise method properly. No exceptions are thrown at all.

The problem seems to be in the callback, debugging the library source code seems that *ProcessCallback* method is not being called anymore.

My system setup is a Windows Server 2012 64 bits

Comment: Did anybody manage to solve this ? Can't find any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and can't find any solution to fix it. However, for a workaround, I will listen to the update event, and when it is stopped, I will re-initialize the Client object and it should work again.

Not a best solution but it resolves for my problem. Any solution that helps on the root one, will be still really appreciate.