# NDde loses OnAdvise event after random period

Tags: .net, dde, ndde

I know there is already a question related to this, but still no answer.

[NDde server stops getting OnAdvise callbacks after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629352/ndde-server-stops-getting-onadvise-callbacks-after-a-while)

I was study and debug for a long time but still can't find out the problem. It looks like there is no any exception raised from NDde, but it still lost of OnAdvice event for a Client, while some other Clients still still recieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just posted an comment to the link too. You might want to re-initialize the Client object each time it lost of the event.